# Key Vault Secret Time Expiry

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to set an expiry date that is dynamic in a Terraform template. The idea is to get current date and add 6 months to that date and use that as the expiry date for the secret, however I am struggling to do so.

I am trying to achieve this using the **time_offset** and **timestamp()** but it isn't working and I get the following error.

**main.tf**

```
resource "time_offset" "expiry_date" {
  offset_months = 6
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "local_admin_pwd" {
    name = "LocalAdminPassword"
    value = random_password.pwd.result
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
    expiration_date = timestamp(time_offset.expiry_date.rfc3339)
}
```

**error**

```
│ Error: Too many function arguments
│ 
│   on key_vault/main.tf line 56, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "local_admin_pwd":
│   56:     expiration_date = timestamp(time_offset.expiry_date.rfc3339)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling timestamp()
│ 
│ Function "timestamp" expects only 0 argument(s).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `timestamp` function does not expect any arguments:

> Function "timestamp" expects only 0 argument(s).

The `expiration_date` argument should get the value from the attribute provided by the `time_offset` resource only:

```
expiration_date = time_offset.expiry_date.rfc3339
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my code correct as it was a typo, but when I rerun it, I get the following error (see updated error)

Comment: `timestamp` provides a result for you, it does not require any arguments. So it would probably require only `time_offset` resource to be referenced. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: are you suggesting that I change the **expiration_date** from **timestamp(time_offset.expiry_date.rfc3339)** to just **time_offset.expiry_date.rfc339**

Comment: Well, if that is the format `expiration_date` is expecting, then yes.